# How to use Tor Network on a non-gui server with perl

Tags: perl, ubuntu, tor

I want to write a perl-script that loads content from internet-websites through the TOR network. The script should run on a non-gui ubuntu server (Ubuntu 12.04).

Just to make it clear: I want to install **no** TOR server and **no** TOR browser. I want to install a TOR client that makes it possible for other programs like perl scripts to access web content through the TOR network.

My questions:

- Where do I find a TOR client for a non-gui ubuntu-machine?
- How to install this client?
- Must I install anything else (maybe some additional cpan modules)?
- Do you have a short example perl script that loads a website through the TOR network?

Comment: [Net::Tor::Servers](http://p3rl.org/Net::Tor::Servers) ?

Comment: @Paulchenkiller No, this is not a TOR client. You can use this only to get a list of TOR servers, but you can not use it to connect to the TOR network. Quote: "Perl extension to query a Tor Directory and collect information on servers" - not a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install tor` - then you can either use `proxychains <your command>` OR `usewithtor <your command>` OR `torify <your command>`

Comment: Is the package "tor" really the tor client? I don't want to install the tor server or a tor browser.

Comment: the package has it all, it's up to you to only use what you need

Comment: @HubertSch&#246;lnast the Tor package is client as well as server. You can configure it either way.